# Remoter desktop SQL server 2008 connection error

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect sql server 2008 on remote desktop. My remote desktop IP is `192.168.175.174`. The user is `User3`, the password is `user3`, and the database is `apache_camel`.

it give an error like this
any buddy can help me to connection

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'User3'.
at     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196    )
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2532)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at database.Sqlserver_connection.main(Sqlserver_connection.java:22)
```

This is my class code:

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;

public class Sqlserver_connection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl =        "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.175.174:1433;DatabaseName=apache_camel;user=User3;password=user3";
        //String Connectionurl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=YourDBName;user=UserName;Password=YourPassword" 
        //"databaseName=HelloWorld;integratedSecurity=true;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                // Establish the connection.
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                    System.out.println(con);
                    // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
                    String SQL = "SELECT TOP 1000 [username],[password] FROM [apache_camel].[dbo].[login]";
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                    // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(1));
                    }
            }

        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, not sure if you "MUST" use SQLServer Driver, here is another driver you could use for the connection (it worked for me on pure java application and on android app), http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ is really easy to use and you could provide the users credentials
throught class DriverManager the static method getConnection(String url, String username, String password), for instance:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.3.67:1433/androiddb", "sa", "1234");

here is a post i made a few weeks ago and i answered myself, it shows specifically how to set the connection with jtds, yes it is for android, but you can skip the specific android steps (it works for MS SQL 2008, i test it on pure java program).

[JTDS for MS SQL in android with ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552082/jtds-for-ms-sql-in-android-with-adt/16590770#16590770)

hope to be helpful, regards.

Comment: sorry it is a problem of username and password I using remote destop id password   it will require sql authentication